# symbol lookup error: cardano-node: undefined symbol: crypto_vrf_publickeybytes

Tags: cardano-node

I am trying to run a cardano node in my local and the command which i am running goes like this.

```
cardano-node run \
   --topology mainnet-topology.json \
   --database-path db \
   --socket-path db/node.socket \
   --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
   --port 3001 \
   --config mainnet-config.json
```

But it is showing me this error.

```
cardano-node: symbol lookup error: cardano-node: undefined symbol: crypto_vrf_publickeybytes
```

In at this post it is getting solved but the links on that post is broken.

Does anyone knows how to resolve the same.

https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-node-symbol-lookup-error-cardano-node-undefined-symbol-crypto-vrf-publickeybytes/36359

The cardano installation progress is here.

```
{
    "era": "Byron",
    "syncProgress": "61.71",
    "hash": "21e4ea98fafcb565733debefca7fecf2d2ab901b7ce6587f1ad4f5ca327e93d1",
    "epoch": 207,
    "slot": 4490076,
    "block": 4487787 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once solution is to add the following to `cabal.project.local`:

```
package cardano-crypto-praos
  flags: -external-libsodium-vrf
```

and then rebuild the `node` executable.

If the file does not already exist, just add at the top level directory of the git checkout, with just the two lines above.

Comment: How do i do this? do i need to execute this command in terminal?

Comment: where is this cabal.project.local i am fairly new to haskel

Comment: The `cabal.project.local` file should be in the top level directory of the Gut checkout. There should already be a `cabal.project` file in the same location.